# std::conditional_variable::wait_for, std::thread::sleep_for on Windows are affected by adjusting clock

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Well. I have Win10 x64 and this pretty simple code:

```
int main() {
    std::conditional_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while(1) {
        cv.wait_for(lock, 1000ms, [](){return false;});
        std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Yes. The code works just like I expect; It shows '!' every second. 
But If I change my local time (minus 1 hour/minute e.g.) it holds forever.
If I replace `cv.wait_for(...)` with WinAPI `Sleep(1000)` it works fine. Also WinAPI `SleepConditionVariableCS` works fine.

I have tried this:

```
cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 1000ms, [](){return false;});
```

And it gives me the same result.

BTW: The behavior of the calls like `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, `std::this_thread::sleep_until` is the same.

So the question is: Is it possible to use `std::condition_variable` with expected behavior? Or I just have to replace it with my own CONDITION_VARIABLE wrapper?

Comment: Thank you for response. The question is because I caught this situation on a laptop when the system time was changed by NTP server. Only couple of minutes was enough for stopping all the process. The process is supposed to be active while the system is active. 

Well "NTP" is not a very usual situation, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: which compiler and what version?

Comment: If `std::steady_clock` jumps, especially backwards, then it's wrong. It's should be a monotonic clock, it should advance only forward, and do it in a steady pace. It should not be adjusted.

Comment: @Mgetz The compiler is from VS 2017.
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24225.1

Comment: @SergioPv seems a bug, you've probably missed the 15.5 window but if you use the 'Report A Problem` button in the IDE there is a chance it'll get fixed for the next toolset update.

Comment: @SergioPv Try using a more up-to-date version of the compiler. Seems like you're currently using MSVC14.0 - the version that came with VS14.

Comment: this c++ api use absolute time (even `wait_for` internal call `wait_until`). as result when absolute time is changed, wait will be affected. from another side `SleepConditionVariableCS` use only relative time and result will be not depend from changing absolute time

Comment: @Mgetz: Sadly it's been reported many times; but can't fix it without a binary breaking release :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was a known bug with VS2015's `condition_variable` which unfortunately is ABI-breaking to fix. I fixed it in our next major release (I completely rewrote the condition variable implementation from scratch), but I don't know when that will happen next. Note that VS2017 was a minor release as far as the standard libraries are concerned.

The problem is that the API contract exposed by `msvcp140.dll` expects an absolute time against the system clock, so if the system clock changes the effective wait length changes. The standard permits implementing an unsteady clock out of a steady clock but not the reverse; my predecessors apparently didn't get that memo :)

Comment: at least it's documented this is the case now, if you have a canonical VSO bug to link to so it can be tracked that would be awesome.

Comment: @BillyONeal Thanks a lot. Could you give me some link to the bug. I just want to add it to the documentation as a reason to write own wrapper. Unfortunately a link to SO is not a reason for our PM :-/

Comment: You could consider releasing a fixed .lib file though.

Comment: @Joshua: Nope, this thing lives in the DLL. We can't fix it in a static lib for the same reason we can't fix it in the headers.

Comment: @BillyONeal: You know you can make static libraries to replace symbols in DLLs right?

Comment: @Joshua Sometimes that's possible, sure. In this case there's shared state though that belongs in the DLL, so that can't really be extracted. (If we didn't have the ConcRT fallback on XP we probably could extract it, but ConcRT is stateful and so torpedoes that whole thing :( )

Comment: Is this fixed in Visual Studio 2019?  How can we know when it will be ok to make an ABI-breaking fix?  If Visual Studio 2017 is not a major release of the standard libraries from Visual Studio 2015, how do we know what IS a major release?  Am I misreading this issue, or does this make wait_for() etc. completely unusable in Visual Studio, since changing the system time might cause your program to hang indefinitely?

Comment: @MadScientist 2019 is 142 so no ABI breakage :(