# Unexpected behavior with `std::chrono::system_clock` and `std::chrono::steady_clock` in `std::condition_variable::wait_until`

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, condition-variable

I'm working with `std::condition_variable::wait_until` in C++ and I'm using `std::chrono::system_clock` and `std::chrono::steady_clock` to manage the waiting time. After reading the documentation, I understand that the sleeping time should not be affected by changes in the system time when using `std::chrono::steady_clock`, while it may change when using `std::chrono::system_clock`.

However, my code is behaving differently: for both clock types, the waiting time is affected by the system time. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> flag = false;
std::condition_variable cv;


void wait_using_system_clock()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(20), [](){return flag.load();});

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference [using system clock] = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() << "s" << std::endl;
}

void wait_using_steady_clock()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(20), [](){return flag.load();});

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference [using steady clock] = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() << "s" << std::endl;
}

void set_system_time_forward()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); // Ensure other threads has executed cv.wait_until
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    tv.tv_sec += 15;
    settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(wait_using_system_clock);
    std::thread t2(wait_using_steady_clock);

    std::thread t3(set_system_time_forward);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I execute the `wait_using_system_clock` and `wait_using_steady_clock` functions on different threads. Another thread is used to change the system time after 2 seconds. I expect that the function `wait_using_steady_clock` should not be affected by this change and should wait for 20 seconds, but instead, both functions finish their execution in approximately 5 seconds, printing:

```
Time difference [using system clock] = 5s
Time difference [using steady clock] = 5s
```

Can anyone help me understand why this discrepancy exists between the expected and actual behavior? Is there something I'm missing in the documentation or misunderstanding about these classes?

Comment: Just don't mix steady_clock and system_clock (they are not equal clocks). System clock can in fact move back and forward in time. steady clock is guaranteed to monotonously increase.

Comment: There is a [long-standing bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359700/1458097) in MSVC that uses `system_clock` instead of `steady_clock` for waiting. Unfortunately, it won't be fixed any time soon, because the fix requires a breaking change in ABI, which Microsoft has [managed to preserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017) between Visual Studio versions 2015 through 2022 to this day. Somewhere I've read that Microsoft's customers deem ABI compatibility very important.

Comment: @heapunderrun, I using GCC/G++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, the `std::mutex`'s in your functions
`wait_using_system_clock` and `wait_using_steady_clock` will not do
anything, because you have to acquire the **SAME** mutex when you
want to lock some data. This can easily be detected by the thread sanitizer.
You can turn it on with the option `-fsanitize=thread` on clang and gcc.

Now, for the part that you are missing about `std::condition_varaible::wait_until`. We know from the documentation that:

> wait_until causes the current thread to block until the condition variable is notified, a specific time is reached, or a spurious wakeup occurs, optionally looping until some predicate is satisfied (`bool(stop_waiting()) == true`).

But the interesting part is in the 2nd paragraph of the [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until#Notes) section:

> Even if the clock in use is std::chrono::steady_clock or another monotonic clock, a system clock adjustment may induce a spurious wakeup.

And that explains why using `std::chrono::steady_clock` in your case made no difference.

Comment: Well, got the point. After making some changes, I could see the expected behavior:

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are violating [this precondition](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition#condvar-29.2):

- `lock.mutex()` returns the same value for each of the lock arguments supplied by all concurrently waiting (via `wait`, `wait_for`, or `wait_until`) threads.

Answer (score 0):

After making changes, I could observe the expected behavior. Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::atomic<bool> flag = false;
std::mutex mtx;

void wait_using_system_clock()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(20), [](){return flag.load();});

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference [using system clock] = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() << "s" << std::endl;
}

void wait_using_steady_clock()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
    cv.wait_until(lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(20), [](){return flag.load();});

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference [using steady clock] = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - begin).count() << "s" << std::endl;
}

void set_system_time_forward()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); // Ensure other thread has executed cv.wait_until
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    tv.tv_sec += 15;
    settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(wait_using_system_clock);
    std::thread t2(set_system_time_forward);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::thread t3(wait_using_steady_clock);
    std::thread t4(set_system_time_forward);
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If we change `tv.tv_sec += 15;` to `tv.tv_sec += 18;` or any other value `>18`, due to the system clock update, there is a spurious wakeup and it prints:

```
Time difference [using system clock] = 2s
Time difference [using steady clock] = 2s
```

Comment: You can safely replace the lambdas passed to `std::condition_varaible::wait_until` with `[](){ return false; }`, making the atomic `flag` variable redundant. I think that you can even remove the lambdas altogether, but I'm not sure on that one.

Comment: @Quasar6, you are right, but this is augmented code from the application just to test the behavior. In production code, the `flag` is being handled properly.